# Cannot play network audio file

Tags: iphone, ios5, audio

In iOS5, the following code works with a local sound file; however when I try the same file which is on the network (and which actually exists) it does not play the sound. It says error -43, but the file is there. I try to reach the network file with the commented out
line.

```
-(void) playSound {

    SystemSoundID soundID;
    //NSURL *path = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.somerealwebtise.com/test.wav"];

    NSURL *path   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"test" withExtension: @"wav"];

    self.sysSoundTestPath = (__bridge CFURLRef)path;

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(self.sysSoundTestPath, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just as you discovered. AudioServices can only play sounds from the local bundle and doesn't have any networking capabilities.

You would need to download the sound from the network URL first and then call `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` with the local file path.